# WP7 SortedDictionary

Tags: windows-phone-7, sorteddictionary

I understand that SortedDictionary is not available in WP7...so have to sort it yourself.

I have found a number of examples and am currently using this code

```
Dictionary<string, TimetableClass> AllClasses = new Dictionary<string, TimetableClass>()
        {
            { "Maths", new TimetableClass {ClassName="Maths", Location="RM1"}},
            { "Physics", new TimetableClass {ClassName="Physics", Location="PM1"}},
            { "English", new TimetableClass {ClassName="English", Location="PM1"}},
            { "Algebra", new TimetableClass {ClassName="Algebra", Location="A1"}}

        };

        var sortedDict = new Dictionary<string, TimetableClass>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TimetableClass> singleclass in AllClasses.OrderBy(key => key.Value))
        {
            sortedDict.Add(singleclass.Key, singleclass.Value);
        }
```

But when I run this I get an exception on the foreach?

Exception is an Unhandled Argument Exception - "Value does bot fall within the expected range"

Really have no idea what I have done wrong here.
Any help appreciated.

- Thanks

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You can't sort a dictionary, once you add the value to the new dictionary the order is lost. You probably want to add the values in a `List<KeyValuePair<string, TimetableClass>>`instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TimetableClass> singleclass in AllClasses.OrderBy(item => item.Key))
        {
            sortedDict.Add(singleclass.Key, singleclass.Value);
        }
```

Alternately, if you want to sort based on Object(Value), try this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TimetableClass> singleclass in AllClasses.OrderBy(item => item.Value.ClassName))
        {
            sortedDict.Add(singleclass.Key, singleclass.Value);
        }
```

And finally, you can also avail this instead of a foreach loop and without the need of an extra 'sortedDict' dictionary.

```
AllClasses = AllClasses.OrderBy(item => item.Key).ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```

Comment: Yes this works fine - thanks!  Just looking at the difference, I realise now that I was trying to order by the object (Value) rather than the key as per your code.   Presumably this was the issue as the object was not able to be 'ordered'?

Comment: Yes exactly! Alternately, if you want to sort based on Object(Value), try this `AllClasses.OrderBy(item => item.Value.ClassName)`